# Awesomium.Net Error on IResourceInterceptor:onFilterNavigation I could not call ExecuteJavascriptWithResult

Tags: awesomium

I have the following error when I call the Javascript function "(dim StrResponse as String=webcontrol1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("CallCopyDocPHP(" & wordQuery & "isnew=0);"))" from IResourceInterceptor method OnFilterNavigation.

The error is "**You cannot access members on a windowed IWebView instance, until you set a valid IWebView.ParentWindow**."

Thanks & Regards 
Vinoth

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I've got the same problem